# xcode crashing when opening the assistant editior

Tags: xcode, xcode4.3

Got the new Retina MacBook and it has not been playing nice with xCode. If i make a new project it works, but if i ty triggering the assistant editor it will freeze. If i save a new project and reopen it, it will freeze. I did install the 4.5 DP and uninstalled it and the latest nonbeta version of xcode and the problem still persists. Anyone know what could be the issue? If i make a new user account xcode is behaving normally. Anyone know of a fix? Crash large too large for me to post.

```
Date/Time:       2012-06-30 03:10:29 -0700
OS Version:      10.7.4 (Build 11E2620)
Architecture:    x86_64
Report Version:  9

Command:         Xcode
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Version:         4.3.3 (1178)
Build Version:   3
Project Name:    IDEApplication
Source Version:  1178000000000000
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 8553856
Parent:          launchd [111]

PID:             234
Event:           hang
Duration:        1.76s
Steps:           18 (100ms sampling interval)

Pageins:         44
Pageouts:        0


Process:         Xcode [234]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Architecture:    x86_64
UID:             501

  Thread 0x810        DispatchQueue 1
  User stack:
    18 ??? (in Xcode) [0x107b73eec]
      18 NSApplicationMain + 867 (in AppKit) [0x7fff85edf244]
        18 -[NSApplication run] + 555 (in AppKit) [0x7fff85c630c6]
          18 -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] + 366 (in IDEKit) [0x1085c2dd1]
            18 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 4282 (in AppKit) [0x7fff85ccc536]
              18 -[NSApplication _handleKeyEquivalent:] + 526 (in AppKit) [0x7fff85dd3175]
                18 -[NSMenu performKeyEquivalent:] + 281 (in AppKit) [0x7fff85dd4524]
                  18 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:] + 125 (in AppKit) [0x7fff85e56932]
                    18 -[NSMenuItem _corePerformAction] + 399 (in AppKit) [0x7fff85e56bfb]
                      18 -[IDEApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 154 (in IDEKit) [0x1085c7096]
                        18 -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 318 (in DVTKit) [0x107e76866]
                          18 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 139 (in AppKit) [0x7fff85d69f7e]
                            18 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 61 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff8a15270d]
                              18 -[IDEWorkspaceTabController _changeToEditorMode:] + 361 (in IDEKit) [0x108728088]
                                18 _NSSetIntValueAndNotify + 259 (in Foundation) [0x7fff86f8353f]
                                  18 -[IDEEditorArea setEditorMode:] + 384 (in IDEKit) [0x108604a61]
                                    18 -[IDEEditorArea _refreshEditorContextsAndPreserveCurrentEditorHistoryStack:] + 642 (in IDEKit) [0x108604d8e]
                                      18 +[DVTLayoutView_ML _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:] + 108 (in DVTKit) [0x107e858ec]
                                        18 +[DVTLayoutView_ML
```

Comment: Have you updated your new mac by clicking `Software Update` some times many bugs solve by updating software

Comment: If the problem persists go to apple care near by & tell them. There might be any corrupt file in OS X, so go to Apple care and they will guide you to resolve the problem. Currently i'm using same software Mac os 10.7.4 with xcode 4.3.3. I didnt get this problem ever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced similar problems on my Retina MacBook. The workaround is to specify "Open in Low Resolution" for Xcode in the Finder. From http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5266:

1. Quit the application if it is currently open.
2. In the Finder, choose Applications from the Go menu.
3. In the Applications folder that opens, click the application's icon so it is highlighted.
4. Choose Get Info from the File menu.
5. Place a checkmark next to "Open in Low Resolution" to enable Low Resolution mode.
6. Close the window and double click the Application to reopen it.

This does have an impact on text quality, though it's not awful (subjective). Hopefully Apple will update Xcode soon.

Comment: found the same solution, hope its fixed soon

Answer (score 7):

For me, the solution was simple:

1. Close Xcode
2. Delete the following folders/files from myProject.xcodeproj (or .xcworkspace if you're using cocoapods) (right click on the file and choose “Show Package Contents”)

   - /xcuserdata
   - /project.xcworkspace
3. Reopen Xcode and enjoy

The crash is occurring due to a corruption in project's userdata content.

Also, you should note that after deleting those files, the window size and position will reset and the opened tabs will be all closed.

Comment: These instructions worked for me on Xcode 10 and were a life saver. I was starting to have a total meltdown. Thanks!

Comment: Fixed my issue perfectly. THANKYOU!!

Answer (score -1):

I am facing the same problem .... I solve it after make changes as per screenshot -

[image]

it works for me.

Comment: you cannot reach those settings if xcode keeps crashing, which is what OP is describing

Comment: @RaduUrsache you can reach just try once. you got.