# Xcode crashes every time when I try to open PROJECT info

Tags: ios, xcode

I have encountered a strange problem recently. My Xcode keeps crashing each and every time when I try to open the project info of every project I have.

By project info I am referring to this:

[image]

However, everything else seem to work perfectly, including building archives, running builds on both simulator and real devices.

Also, I have tried many methods, such as deleting /DerivedData and /xuserdata, but none of them turn out to be helpful.

Here is part of the problem report for Xcode, in case you need to take a deep look inside it:

```
Process:               Xcode [27134]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               7.2.1 (9548.1)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-9548001000000000~2
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [27134]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-03-14 15:29:00.281 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F1021)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        B26CD753-E360-FF23-061B-BF9FE89BE0BA

Sleep/Wake UUID:       C8671DD6-AC38-4218-80F7-565C6A32EB44

Time Awake Since Boot: 120000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       20000 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 7C1002
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[DVTMacroExpansionStringList_NonLiteral length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff3ddab6e50
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: 
  0: Replacement view is installing: <Xcode3ProjectInfoEditor: 0x7ff3e4f1c8c0 representing: (null)>
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff85528024 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x000000010ea3fb07 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00007fff8595176e objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3  0x00007fff8552b0ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] (in CoreFoundation)
  4  0x00007fff85470e24 ___forwarding___ (in CoreFoundation)
  5  0x00007fff85470998 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 (in CoreFoundation)
  6  0x000000012196b2fa -[Xcode3ProjectInfoEditor projectDeploymentOSForPlatform:] (in Xcode3UI)
  7  0x00000001218d19b1 -[Xcode3ProjectInfoEditor iOSProjectDeploymentOS] (in Xcode3UI)
  8  0x00000001218d18b4 -[Xcode3ProjectInfoEditor _reloadSDKAndDeploymentBuildSettings] (in Xcode3UI)
  9  0x00000001218d1679 -[Xcode3ProjectInfoEditor _updateSDKAndDeployment] (in Xcode3UI)
 10  0x00000001218d0dfa -[Xcode3ProjectInfoEditor setInspectedBlueprint:] (in Xcode3UI)
 11  0x00000001218d0568 -[Xcode3ProjectEditor replacementView:didInstallViewController:] (in Xcode3UI)
 12  0x000000010efd3201 __42-[DVTReplacementView _setupViewController]_block_invoke (in DVTKit)
 13  0x000000010ea3f845 DVTInvokeWithFailureHint (in DVTFoundation)
 14  0x000000010eef947b -[DVTReplacementView _setupViewController] (in DVTKit)
 15  0x000000010eef92ff -[DVTReplacementView installedViewController] (in DVTKit)
 16  0x000000010eeff8ec -[DVTReplacementView layoutTopDown] (in DVTKit)
 17  0x000000010f0b801d +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] (in DVTKit)
 18  0x000000010f0b80fa +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] (in DVTKit)
 19  0x000000010f0b80fa +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] (in DVTKit)
 20  0x000000010f0b80fa +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] (in DVTKit)
 21  0x000000010f0b80fa +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] (in DVTKit)
 22  0x000000010f0b80fa +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] (in DVTKit)
 23  0x000000010f0b80fa +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] (in DVTKit)
 24  0x000000010f0b80fa +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] (in DVTKit)
 25  0x000000010f0b80fa +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] (in DVTKit)
 26  0x000000010f0b80fa +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] (in DVTKit)
 27  0x000000010f0b80fa +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] (in DVTKit)
 28  0x000000010f0b80fa +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] (in DVTKit)
 29  0x000000010f0b80fa +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] (in DVTKit)
 30  0x000000010f0b80fa +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] (in DVTKit)
 31  0x000000010f0b80fa +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] (in DVTKit)
 32  0x000000010f0b80fa +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] (in DVTKit)
 33  0x000000010f0b80fa +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] (in DVTKit)
 34  0x000000010eeff4c4 +[DVTLayoutView_ML _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:] (in DVTKit)
 35  0x000000010ef15b20 +[DVTLayoutView_ML _layoutWindow:] (in DVTKit)
 36  0x000000010f0b7eb5 __44+[DVTLayoutView_ML scheduleWindowForLayout:]_block_invoke_2 (in DVTKit)
 37  0x000000010e9a3ce5 -[DVTRunLoopToken _DVTRunLoopToken_perform] (in DVTFoundation)
 38  0x00007fff86795641 __NSFirePerformWithOrder (in Foundation)
 39  0x00007fff85444127 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation)
 40  0x00007fff85444080 __CFRunLoopDoObservers (in CoreFoundation)
 41  0x00007fff85436188 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 42  0x00007fff85435bd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 43  0x00007fff8ca9456f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 44  0x00007fff8ca941ee ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 45  0x00007fff8ca9412b _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
 46  0x00007fff848a18ab _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 47  0x00007fff848a0e58 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 48  0x000000010f01c0c2 -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 49  0x00007fff84896af3 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 50  0x00007fff84813244 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 51  0x00007fff888a55c9 start (in libdyld.dylib)

abort() called
```

Comment: How old is your project?  I see a `Xcode3ProjectInfoEditor` in the hints section.  Is there any way you can update / upgrade the project to be Xcode 7 compatible, or at least more modern?

Comment: There is two possibility 1. this project develop in old xcode version and you are try to open in new that some file not supported. 2. clear detive data close xcode and reset simulator then check might be that solve

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273232/xcode-crashing-when-opening-the-assistant-editior and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076701/xcode-systemic-crash-on-open-project-how-to-reset-xcode-assistant-editor

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, the project is indeed an old one, but its deployment target is now 6.1 and it works fine with Xcode7, except for this issue. Could you be more elaborate on the update/upgrade thing?

Comment: @NitinGohel, this issue happens recently, although I can't remember the exact date. Before then, nothing had gone wrong. And I have already tried the DerivedData, nothing helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading the project by going to your Project Settings and clicking on the File Inspector (i.e. the panel or tab that appears on the right side of the IDE window).

One of the popup menus that appears should be "Project Format".

Choose "Xcode 6.3 compatible" and see if that makes life nicer for you.

[image: Choose Xcode 6.3 compatible]]

Comment: Unfortunately, no... But I add something more to the crash report, I am not sure if that would help... I am suspecting that this issue may happen after I adopted CocoaPods.

Comment: I'm not an Apple engineer and I don't work on the Xcode team, so I don't know exactly what the backtrace means... but are you still seeing the error after you updated the project format?  Also, are you opening the xcode ***project*** or the ***workspace*** (`.xcworkspace`) file, the latter of which is what you should be opening when working with CocoaPods.

Comment: Yes, the error also shows up. I have tried both project and workspace files and they all have the same result, which is crash.